# how to fix addons path problem in odoo 11 in windows 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

;addons_path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Odoo 11/server/odoo/addons,C:/Program Files (x86)/Odoo 11/server/odoo/custom_addons

The path doesn't work in odoo 11

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the beginning, it means the line is a comment?

Answer (score 0):

That path is didn't taken for run odoo11 server as that path contains **semicolon (;)** at the beginning of line which denoted as a comment in config file. So remove that semicolon and re-run. That will work.